# Feature-IDE AllConfigurationGenerator algorithm complexity

Tags: configuration, generator, featuretools, code-complexity

FeatureIDE allows to generate all possible valid configuration for a product line model (AllConfigurationGenerator).
What is the followed logic to achieve that? I know that FeatureIDE uses SAT solver to check a configuration validity, which is an NP-Complete. Does this mean an exponential complexity?
Anyone has analyzed the code from this perspective?

Sure the big O depends on the number of features, the number of related constraints (XOR, require, exclude) and probably the number od features involved in the constraints.